Can I set lifecycle phase in the Maven pom.xml `<resources>` element?
In my POM I have a <resources> section inside <build>.  This appears to be a shorthand for the maven-resources-plugin, I guess.  It doesn't go in the <plugins> section.  I'd like to do some resource filtering in the generate-sources lifecycle phase, which is not the default, so I tried to add a <phase> element.
It doesn't work; I get "Malformed POM ... Unrecognized tag: 'phase'".
The POM structure I'm trying is like this:
<project>
...
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
           <directory>src</directory>
           <filtering>true</filtering>
           <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        ...
    <plugins>
</build>
</project>

Is there a way to accomplish this in the "build->resources" element, or do I need to configure the plugin in the "plugins" element?

Simple answer: No... the question which coming into my mind: Why do you change the directory and also why using filtering through generated phase? Can you give more real example maybe a link to an existing project on github or alike ?

The scenario is this: I want to write the maven @project.version@ into a typescript file, part of an Angular app.  That has to happen before the frontend-maven-plugin runs (in "generate-resources") to compile the typescript.

You cannot add a <phase> to the <resources> section, but you can add it to the maven resources plugin by mentioning it explicitly in your POM like
 <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
...

